# for condition not updating: python

Tags: python, for-loop

I have program that needs logic like changing for condition per every loop. See the code to understand clearly.

**Program**:
I have two lists which contain again lists(`a` and `b`). If 2nd element of `a`'s sub list matched to 2nd element of `b`'s sub list, both have to delete.

**Code:**

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], ['1', '2'], ['#', '$' '%']]
b = [['c', 'b'], ['0', '2']]

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(b)):
        if a[i][1] == b[j][1]:
            del a[i]
            del b[j]
print(a)
print(b)
```

**Error**:
IndexError. I can understand it's because of `for` condition.

By using `break` and `continue` it's becoming complex.
So any alter solution for this?

Comment: You are modifying the length of the list *while iterating over its original length*. What did you expect would happen?!

Comment: Is it important that the list is modified in-place?

Comment: @jonrsharpe. The len of variable changed. So for condition should also change. But it's not changing.

Comment: @SGG `len(a)` is evaluated **only once**, as an argument to `range` when the `for` loop starts - it doesn't update each time the loop repeats.

Comment: Modifying the list while traversing through it is not recommended.You should save the indices and delete them after the loop.

Comment: What about the following lists: `a = [[1,2,3]]` and `b = [[1,2,3],[3,2,1]]`.  Should both elements of b be removed, or just the first one?

Comment: Why does this have to be in place? Just generate new lists where these items do not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual approach is not to delete from lists within loops.  The whole construct is quite inefficient anyway.  Determine the elements that need to be deleted and then create new lists without those elements:

```
A = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], ['1', '2'], ['#', '$' '%']]
B = [['c', 'b'], ['0', '2']]

C = set(a[1] for a in A) & set(b[1] for b in B)

A = [a for a in A if a[1] not in C]
B = [b for b in B if b[1] not in C]

print(A)
print(B)
```

Comment: The list needs to be modified in-place according to the OP.

Comment: @JamieCockburn Then replace the contents of the old lists with the new ones.  `A[:] = …`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that when you remove an item (say from `b`), the range is already determined, and so the index goes out of range.

You can solve this by iterating backwards as @RevanProdigalKnight points out:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], ['1', '2'], ['#', '$' '%']]
b = [['c', 'b'], ['0', '2']]

for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
    for j in range(len(b)-1,-1,-1):
        if a[i][1] == b[j][1]:
            del a[i]
            del b[j]
            break
print(a)
print(b)
```

If you want to **remove only one row in `b`** if equivalent.

If on the other hand you wish to remove all copies in `b`, try:

```
for i in range(len(a)-1,-1,-1):
    key = a[i][1]
    removed = 0
    for j in range(len(b)-1,-1,-1):
        if key == b[j][1]:
            del b[j]
            removed = 1
    if removed == 1
        del a[i]
print(a)
print(b)
```

**Difference?**

Say you have two arrays:

```
a = [[0,0],[1,1],[2,2]]
b = [[0,0],[2,1],[3,0]]
```

Then using the first algorithm will result in:

```
a = [[2,2]]
b = [[0,0]]
```

While the second will result in:

```
a = [[2,2]]
b = []
```

Comment: This can be solved by iterating over the list backwards using `range(len(object),0)`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Indeed. However you must set the step to `-1` and `len(object)-1`

Comment: And one will need to do something to break out of the inner loop too.

Comment: What if there are more than one equation ?

Comment: More than one, you can simply and them together?

Comment: @mauve: indeed, but this would be slightly less efficient.

Comment: @CommuSoft: in python 2, range returns a list. reversed returns an iterator on that list, only reversed. I think the efficiency of that is minimal at best. In python 3, on the other hand, range returns an iterator, meaning reversed has to list it first, i would think.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to keep track of the indices that you want to delete, and then remove them afterwards starting from the highest index, going down to the lowest.

EDIT: An implementation;

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b'], ['1', '2'], ['#', '$' '%']]
b = [['c', 'b'], ['0', '2']]

a_del = []
b_del = []

for i in range(0, len(a)):
    for j in range(0, len(b)):
        if a[i][1] == b[j][1]:
            a_del.append(i)
            b_del.append(j)

for idx in reversed(a_del):
    del a[idx]

for idx in reversed(b_del):
    del b[idx]

print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score -1):

Possible fix

```
for data in zip(a,b):
if (data[0][1] == data[1][1]):
    #do whatever
```

Comment: This requires to copy the values I assume. Which can be very labour intensive.

Comment: @Hima The original compares every element from `a` with every element from `b`, yours just pairs on the same index _and_ just the the elements up to the length of the shorter of both lists.

Comment: @BlackJack +1 to your answer ! Superb .

Comment: But the requirement is on the same index only .. no need to compare all -> all .

Comment: @Hima If that were the requirement then the code in the question wouldn't trigger the exception because nothing would have to be deleted and the OP would not have nested the two loops.

Comment: this yields a different result from what the code in the question would yield, weren't it for the index error. I consider this an incorrect answer.

Comment: @BlackJack Ah ! My bad , i meant same element 2nd here but anyway its wrong approach.